# What does competitiveness of a journal mean?

Tags: journals, bibliometrics

I was looking at metrics on Letpub for few journals. For competitiveness, few journals had "very difficult", few had "86%" while some other had "2%". What does the percentages represent? Is it similar to acceptance rate?

Example:
https://www.letpub.com/index.php?journalid=765&page=journalapp&view=detail

Comment: From that page: "All review process metrics, such as acceptance rate and review speed, are limited to our user-submitted manuscripts. As such they may not reflect the journals' exact competitiveness or speed."

Answer (score 1):

Based on the percentages, I would guess that "competitiveness" here means how many articles are accepted out of those that are submitted. Elsevier sees a much lower acceptance percentage, which makes sense, because the people who submit the worst papers that get desk rejected don't likely report what happened to the database. In the same way Elsevier reports a much shorter average review duration compared to the user-reported ones.